# Python 3: Convert string from utf-8 to ascii

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

I am using Python 3.x and have a string that contains utf-8 characters, like this:

```
link='https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com'
```

I would now like to convert the string to ascii, so that it reads 'https://www.google.com'. How can I achieve this? I have tried

```
link.decode('utf-8')
```

which throws the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Is there not an easy way to simply decode a string containing utf-8 characters to plain ascii characters?

Comment: URL encoding and UTF-8 encoding are two independent things.

Comment: There are no UTF-8 characters in that string (except the ones which are plain ASCII are of course technicalny *also* UTF-8 characters, trivially).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use urllib.parse.unquote, it will automatically handle the decoding for you https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote :

```
$ python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24)
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> url = unquote('https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com')
>>> url
'https://www.google.com'
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.